# access each Telerik control in my form

Tags: c#, telerik

I use # and window application

How can I found telerik controls in my form.

something like code bellow. but for telerik controls

> foreach (Control Ctrl in this.Controls)
>        {}

thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you are using Winforms :

All RadControls derive from [RadControl](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/tpf-class-hierarchy-radcontrol.html)

therefore you could do the following :

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
     RadControl rc = ctrl as RadControl;
     if (rc != null)
     {
          //Do code for RadControl here
     }
}
```

or a LINQ based solution

```
var ctrls = this.Controls.OfType<RadControl>();

foreach (RadControl ctrl in ctrls)
{
    //Do Something...
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to check recursively through the controls child controls on the form, as a radcontrol may be within another control on the form i.e. within a group box.

Comment: thanks alot . it works . and would you please . make an an example, with group box. my rad controls are in group box